# PDF Rendering issues in IE 8 & above using ASP.Net

Tags: pdf, iframe

I have been plucking my hair and hitting my head all around due to the PDF rendering issues. All is well when we used IE 7 & below. But this year we started supporting the latest browsers IE 8 & above and everything goes wild.

Actually I have used an iframe to render the inline PDF, this works fine with IE7 & below But now using IE8, lot of users started complaining that the PDF is displayed as blank inside the iframe (just displays a grey box). I have used the following code to render the pdf in iframe.

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.Buffer = false;

 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-length", doc.Length.ToString());
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

 Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", doc.Length.ToString());
 Response.BinaryWrite(doc);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.Close();
 Response.End();
```

But it didn't work properly. Then after googling I thought of using  tag to render the pdf. So, for that I first created the pdf document and stored in the server. But in this approach also I have two issues:

1) The file is not getting created properly. See the below methods which I tries to create the PDF file using byte[] array. Also, this works perfectly in my local but in the server it both method creates a 1 KB file. I think it is unable to write the whole byte[] array.

```
 a) System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileFullPath, doc);
 b) using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileFullPath,  System.IO.FileMode.Create))
   {
       stream.Write(attestationDoc, 0, attestationDoc.Length);
   }
```

2) This is the object tag I am using but the problem is, this works only when the  file resides in the root of the project and it is not working if the file is inside any other project folder. Actually I tried to use Server.MapPath but it is not working.

```
 <object data="data\test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="860px" height="470px">
        <embed src="data\test.pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
 </object>
```

So, please help me it is very urgent.

If any of the above method works I am fine that.